# How to use LDAP for authentication in Craft CP (back end)

Tags: authentication

Where only users in Active Directory can login to the Craft Control Panel.

Answer (score 3):

There's a feature request [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1471) that would allow custom login forms for the Craft Control Panel login page you might want to add a comment to.

In the meantime, there is a [`userSession.onBeforeAuthenticate`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#userSession-onBeforeAuthenticate) event a plugin can listen to to perform any 3rd party authentication.

You can see how a similar plugin did this for front-end LDAP logins here: 
 https://github.com/thepitagroup/adldap_craftcms

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got LDAP working. would you help how to set the user session  and permissions? I do not want to save to craft user table.

Comment: @youme Can you link to how you got LDAP working?